# Using self keyword from a category

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-category

I have an implementation like the following:

```
@implementation foo (bar)
- (NSAttributedString *) method1
{
  ...
  [self bar: ...]
  ...
}
+(void) bar:...
{
  ...
}
```

The error is that is says "No visible @interface for foo declares the selector bar:.."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: BTW, it's convention that classes start with an uppercase letter (i.e. `Foo` instead of `foo`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`bar` is a class method, use `[foo bar]` instead.

Comment: Glad it worked, @user3642365.  There's an official way to state that here.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write `[[self class] bar]`.   This is the preferred way if your intention is for any future subclass of your `foo` class to call that subclass' own implementation of `bar` instead of the original `bar` from `foo`.

Comment: @Josh Caswell.   Thanks for pointing this out.   I reworded my answer to reflect what I actually wanted it to mean.